# Codeigniter URI routing not working 404 error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

my view is :-

```
<li class="">
  <a class="" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Login"> 
  <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>&nbsp;Login </a>
</li>
```

my Login Controler

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
         $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

When i clicked on link it says 404 page not found.
but when edit the link manually and write **/index.php/Login** it is working fine. how to fix this...

Comment: Examine the rendered code to verify the URL.  What other troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: when viewing the source of url its showing currect url.. when i edit url in address bar of browser **base_url()/index.php/Controller** it is working currect.

Comment: `base_url()` is a server side PHP function, which is executed *before* the page is ever rendered.  It's meaningless in the address bar of a browser.

Comment: yes Sparky i know that.. i only try to explain my problem. my addressbar is currently showing localhost/timesofeducation/ which i set to base url. and my default controller is Home. and above mentioned code i created a Controller Login when i clicked on Login link the Url showing localhost/timesofeducation/Login which is currect. but its showing 404 error . when i edit manually localhost/timesofeducation/index.php/Login its works.

Comment: Have you got a htaccess file for it out side of application folder? Also check base url set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use 3 more steps:

1. create a `.htaccess` file on project root(on your project folder "/project" or domain root directory)

Insert following line of codes on `.htaccess` file.

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

2. Find config/congig.php file and change this line to-

*add base url in my case:

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cirest.dev/';` ( assign your project path/URL)

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

3. ADD this HTML to your view:

`<li>`

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>">`

`<i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>&nbsp;Login </a>`

`</li>`

I think it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `site_url()` in place of `base_url()`

`<a class="" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>Login">`

Comment: let me know, what url is appears now?

Comment: same url as base_url()

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should properly define url in **config/routes.php**:

```
$route['login'] = 'login/index';
```

And then you can use this route in a template with **site_url()** function:

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo site_url('login'); ?>"> 
  <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>&nbsp;Login </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in the webroot and name it  .htaccess then type this code in it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And in your application/config/config.php file, find this

```
$config ['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed from **$route['login'] = ['login/index'];** to **$route['login'] = 'login/index';**  in my case.